# Какая приставка и корень будет в этих словах?

Tags: орфография

Какая приставка и корень будет в этих словах ?

1. смотр
2. дело
3. летят
4. земля
5. веселый
6. чистый

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В обоих словах приставок нет.

1. *Смотр*: корень — **смотр**.
2. *Дело*: корень — **де**.

Любое слово по составу можно проверить [**здесь**](http://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%A1/%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80).

Comment: Интересно, почему в слове _смотр_ нет окончания... А у однокоренных слов с _делать_ нет того самого _л_ в корне: де-л-а-ть, деj-а-тель-ø...

Comment: @Aer Спасибо, что натолкнули на поиски. Про окончание понятно, что нулевое, но про них не спрашивалось. В морфемном разборе не силён. Исправил корень на _де_  и полез на просторы интернета. Везде, где смотрел, пишут про корень _дел_. Собственно, я вот почему пишу. Этимологически, конечно, _деятель, дело_ и пр. являются родственными и, может быть, до какого-то времени были однокоренными, а сейчас расходятся. В каком-то ответе Грамоты было сказано, что этимологически родственные слова в настоящее время могут быть не однокоренными и, соответственно, не могут быть проверочными друг для друга.

Comment: Но тут все-таки я бы не стал говорить, что связь потерялась. Так же, как ши-л-о, как ни крути, нужно, чтобы ши-ть, а мы-л-о, чтобы мы-ть...

Comment: @Aer  Скорее всего, Вы правы. Связь-то в любом случае остаётся, но с формальной, что ли, точки зрения идет расхождение. Не знаю. Мне, например, кажется, что _деятель_ по семантике ближе к _действию_, а "_делатель_" к _деланию_.